# Copying stdin to a buffer

Tags: go, buffer

I want to copy a `os.Stdin` string to a buffer, to check for a user inputted text (e.g. "hibye") and put an if statement against it.

My current code just handles simple stdin stdiout copy operations (no buffer):

```
func interact(c net.Conn) {
    // Read from Reader and write to Writer until EOF()
    copy := func(r io.ReadCloser, w io.WriteCloser) {
        defer func() {
            r.Close()
            w.Close()
        }()
        n, err := io.Copy(w, r)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("[%s]: ERROR: %s\n", c.RemoteAddr(), err)
            log.Println(n)
        }
    }

    go copy(c, os.Stdout)
    go copy(os.Stdin, c)
}
```

**Question:** What is the most efficient way to implement a use of a buffer to have control over the passed strings?

bad example (failed attempt):

```
buf := make([]byte, 1024)
go copy (os.Stdin, []byte(buf))
if buf == "hibye" {
do stuff
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `ioutil.ReadAll` might be a better fit for your scenario than `io.Copy`.

Comment: Why do you run the copy statement with a go routine?

Comment: Let me get that straight: We are talking of a text based protocol, presumably via a network connection and you are optimizing the way to deal with a byte buffer with a length of 1k to shave away a few µs?

Comment: I run the copy statement with a go routine because I'm trying to modify an existing github code (gonc - go implementation of netcat). I didn't understand the latter question - My program listens for TCP connections and starts a reverse bash shell (the interaction code is written in first post) - My issue is that i'm trying to read a string from within this connection that won't be interpreted as a system command like now (since the terminal becomes a bash shell on the target host after the interaction)